# How can I make a css animation that doesn't get "stuck" at each end

Tags: css, css-animations

The code that I currently have is:

```
.pulsing {
    -webkit-animation: color_change 1s infinite alternate;
    color: rgba(161, 8, 40, 0.9);
}

@-webkit-keyframes color_change {
    0% { color: rgba(161, 8, 40, 0.9); }
    100% { color: red; }

}
```

[Demo here](https://jsfiddle.net/8c4zgwy2/1/)

The problem is that it gets to 100% and stays there for (presumably) 2 seconds. I would like it to hit 100% and then immediately reverse, or maybe stay at the 100% color for 0.25 seconds or something, but I'm not sure how to do this.

Comment: I think it is working the way you want, its just that the change is colour is subtle so its not so noticeable. If you change it to `0% { color: blue; } 100% { color: yellow; }` It looks fine: https://jsfiddle.net/ax9em8jc/

Comment: ya @FluffyKitten is right you pick 2 red colors so its look like it stays in the red color for long time, but this his happens due to that 2 colors close to each other and it gets to the red color so you have 1s remain for out of 1.5s because it took for him

Comment: In that case I guess my question is how can I make it so it doesn't look like it stays in the red color for a long time, but still using the same colors?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This may seem like a weird bug, and I will go one bit further and tell you how I solved this.

I use Chrome most of the times, but when it comes to CSS then Firefox is unbeatable. I selected your `.pulsing` element and selected the Animation tab. Here you can see clearly what's going on.

[image]

Look at the purple field. You have an ease-in-ease-out transition timing function as a default and, because you alternate, the yellow will just be briefly seen because it will be in both the ease-in and the ease-out animation.

Just add `linear` to the animation to make that purple area straight. If you want to make it stay longer on yellow (which I used in the example below), you need to create a custom bezier transition timing function. Perhaps so that the orange part of the animation (see image) is around 50%. Otherwise it will still look like the animation is stopping on red.

```css
.pulsing {
    -webkit-animation: color_change 1s infinite alternate linear;
    color: yellow;
}

@-webkit-keyframes color_change {
    0% { color: yellow; }
    100% { color: red; }

}
```

```html
<div class="pulsing">
 TEXT
</div>
```

Comment: Awesome - I hadn't thought about the easing! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```css
.pulsing {
    -webkit-animation: 1s color_change infinite;
}

@-webkit-keyframes color_change {
    0% {
        color: rgba(161, 8, 40, 0.9);
    }

    50% {
        color: red;
    }

    100% {
        color: rgba(161, 8, 40, 0.9);
    }
}
```

Comment: well he don't need to reverse manually as I recall it when it finish the cycle it reverses by itself

Comment: This is closer, but it still looks like it stays on the red for too long (even if that's just because the colors are close). I upped the animation time to 5 seconds and the effect is even more obvious.

Answer (score 0):

the thing is it's not really stuck there it's just got to the 100% and then he stays there for the rest of the time.
think about you put 1s and it got to the 100% in 200ms so it got 800ms to finish the cycle

```
.pulsing {
    -webkit-animation: color_change 3s infinite alternate;
    color: rgba(161, 8, 40, 0.9);
}

@-webkit-keyframes color_change {
    0% { color: green; }
    100% { color: yellow; }
}
```

in this code, I  use the green and the yellow and when it got to the 3s it reverses itself, it got to the yellow fast so it wait to the 3s to pass to start the reverse.

**UPDATE**
you have 2 option as I see it:

1. make the animation shorter (but it's also make the color transition to accrue faster).
2. do like **@Maverick Fabroa** did and set the color as the 50% and the 100% be the first color like this:

   @-webkit-keyframes color_change {
   0% { color: green; }
   50% { color: yellow; }
   100% { color: green; }
   }

Comment: In that case, my question is how do I make it take the whole 1000ms to get to 100%?

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately it's still not quite the effect I'm after. I actually want the color change to be slower in the end (maybe 5 seconds) but to look like it reverses as soon as it hits the bright red, even though the colors are close. Even with the 50 and 100% it still looks like it gets stuck.